# need to bind a property value in WPF dynamically

Tags: wpf, binding

this is my code

```
<Canvas Name="chartCanvas1" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Beige">
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
           <TransformGroup>
               <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" /> 
               <TranslateTransform Y="355" />
           </TransformGroup>
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

i need to bind the Y="355" to a value from the code behind class in runtime and convert the coordinate system to the natural coordinate system used in mathematics.

problem is i don't know how to do that.
some one please help me out.

regards,
rangana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) for this that does your conversion between the two coordinate systems. And the bind to it in XAML:

```
<TranslateTransform Y="{Binding SomeDataProperty Converter={StaticResource myCoordinateConverter}}" />
```

Alternatively if you'd use [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) your ViewModel would take the mathematical coordinate from the model, convert it to the WPF coordinate system an provide a property for that where the view (the XAML) can directly bind against.